# BOOST BGL edge index probleme when copying graph or agrument passing probleme

Tags: c++, function, boost, graph, arguments

i have a problem about edges using in a boost graph of type:

```
adjacency_list < listS, vecS, undirectedS, mes_noeuds, mes_arcs > graph_t;
```

"mes_arcs" is composed by some argument like:

```
struct mes_arcs {
    int idarc;

};
```

When i create edge i store  the `edge_descriptor` of each edge in a vector. Each edge descriptor are stored at the `idarc` position that i gave to the edges trough "mes_arcs".

I declared a struct containing data that i want to pass to a function:

```
struct data_creat_graph {
    graph_t g_new;
    std::vector<edge_descriptor>old_v_edges;
    std::vector<edge_descriptor>new_v_edges;
    std::vector<int> node_to_del;
    std::vector<int> edge_to_del;

};
```

the function look like:

```
  creat_new_graph( data_creat_graph &dcg){
         graph_t g
         std_vector new_edge;
         edge_descriptor e_d;
         ...
         //create the new graph
         e_d = add_edge(v1,v2,g).first;
         new_edge[ind]= edge_descriptor;
         g[e_d].idarc=ind; 
         ...
         //populate the struct             
         dcg.g_new=g;
         dcg.new_v_edge=new_edge;  
}
```

My probleme is that when i look at the value `dcg.g_new[dcg.new_v_edge[..]].idarc` into the function (by writing to a debug file) i have the good value of "`idarc`" but when i try to use that vector outside of the function the value of idarc is totaly wrong.

So i'm wondering if it's a problem of the way of passing argument to a function or if it's about using boost edge index or something like that wwhen i copy the graph by `dcg.g_new=g` ?

I tried to find an answer on stackoverflow but everyone is using BOOST in the way he need it so it's hard to find a answer.

thank you in advance for the time taken to read my question.

Answer (score -1):

In the case of `listS` edge container selector (which you use), the vertex descriptor is *effectively* an iterator into the graph's edge container (which is actually the out edges for each vertex).

If you copy the graph you can *not* use the vertex descriptor from the source because the edge containers have been copied to, and hence the descriptors are different.

---

All in all it looks like you would like to have unique edge-id that are "shared" (the same) across copies. This is what you'd usually use the bundled properties (`mes_arcs`) for.

When you copy the graph here:

```
     dcg.g_new=g;
```

the bundles will be copied fine. Just, when you want to find the appropriate edge by ID you'll have to go all the way using e.g.

```
 es = edges(g_new);
 match = std::find_if(es.first, es.second, [](mes_arcs const& a) { return a.id_arc == 42; });
```

To make reverse-lookup more friendly you can build a map:

```
 map<int, edge_descriptor> rlookup;

 for(std::tie(f,l) = edges(g_new); f!=l; ++f)
    rlookup[g_new[f].id_arc] = f;
```

Alternatively you can use "external" property maps. In this case a Boost Bimap could be adapted so you can have lookups both ways. (I've made some examples that adapt Boost Bimap for use as Boost graph property map, which you should be able to find on SO)

Comment: thank you very much for your quick answer, but does this technic apply for a vecS container too? because i made a mistake in my first question it was a wrong part of code.

Comment: `vecS` are a different ballgame, but at least the techniques with external propertymaps always apply. However, with `vecS` you should be able to take the vertex_descriptor (which is then an integral type) as an id, making things somewhat easier.

Comment: so you mean that normaly if i work with vecs for edges, i have no mapping to do when i use the edge_descriptor that i previously stored for the new copied graph?

Comment: Edge descriptors are another thing. Vertices are stored globally, edgelists  are kept per vertex (this is the nature of an adjacency list). So there is not a global edge index. You still need an edge index property if you want that.